# Invitation letter schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, invitation-letters, schengen-visas

I hold an Indian passport and intend to travel to Europe to meet my German girlfriend and to travel with her a little within Europe. I have heard rumors that the invitation from a girl may result in a refusal of visa as the official might suspect me to be an illegal immigrant. I will be financing my entire trip, lasting 50 days.

Comment: Hi kanwaljeet. Can you be clearer about what question you are asking, please.

Comment: i have an invitation letter from my girlfriend but i doubt the officials may refuse the application, as they might consider me as a person who would not come back

Comment: Has she provided an approved Verpflichtungserklärung?

Comment: she has provided me the copy of the passport, however not her bank statements as i will be financing my own trip

Comment: Although i will stay at her place and she has also provided the address.

Comment: In that case it will not be the invitation that causes problems, it will be the  50 days and trying to justify that.  Go to this one under the section 'Premise'.  http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Comment: why 50 days would be a problem??

Answer (score 3):

Revealing in your application that you're in a long-distance relationship with a resident will make it harder for you to demonstrate that you have reason to leave the Schengen area at the end of the trip you have planned. The relationship will be seen as a reason for you to *stay*, and so you need to show proportionally stronger ties to your home country in order to convince the examining official the balance of your interests will be to leave. It does not *automatically* result in a rejection, though.

On the other hand, *concealing* this fact (which is eminently relevant to your travel plans) would be visa fraud, and that can have much more serious consequences than just having your application denied, if you're found out. So you should certainly declare her in field 31 of the application form.

Unless your girlfriend is providing a formal Verpflichtungserklärung, there's no need to enclose a formal invitation letter, copy of her passport, or that kind of thing. The focus is on establishing *your* conditions -- it's not as if being a citizen gives her any direct "vote" to influence the decisions of the civil service just on her say-so.

Comment: what if once she provides me with Verpflichtungserklärung and lacks in one or two criteria than?  My application would still be ruled out?  if yes, than isn't it better just to provide only the invitation letter and the copy of her passport because this"  Verpflichtungserklärung" is a direct indication that she will bear my expense, food, lodging etc.. but the truth is I will take care of my entire expense and will just stay with her.

Comment: I have return tickets too

Comment: I would advise you to read my answer, just above these comments. Your comment does not sound like you have.

Comment: i just have the letter and the copy of the passport however when i asked her about  Verpflichtungserklärung, she said she will send me this paper. Although she was with me in india and went back last month i doubt she does not have much funds as of now to support anybody. I have return tickets

Comment: @KanwaljeetMahawar: You're still not replying to anything I wrote in my answer -- just having a conversation with your own deluded assumption that the consultate wants to see a photocopy of your girlfriends passport etc., for some unstated otherworldly reason. I cannot prevent you from keeping to talk to yourself based on that false assumption, but kindly take it elsewhere than comment to an answer whose content you don't have any intention of engaging with.