# What are the options when a Schengen visa application is in processing after the proposed travel date?

Tags: visas, schengen, application-status, visa-shopping

My friend has applied for a Schengen visa from the Hungarian Embassy. At the first try the visa was rejected due to insufficient travel insurance. When he re-applied again on the 14th June, the visa status currently shows it is still under process in the embassy while his travel date is 17th June which has now already passed.

In such a situation what happens?

Answer (score 6):

In these cases, the decision-maker has the *option*, but not the *obligation* to refuse the application on...

[Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

...because when the travel dates are passed, the application's premise may no longer be tenable and hence the application is 'incoherent'.  This is how Schengen  decision-makers are taught to apply the rules.

This draconian outcome may not be the case for your friend, but it is always out there in situations like these. We are not prophets and there is also a likelihood the application will be approved.

You can also search the TSE archives here for 'post-submission anxiety' and advise your friend to brass it out.

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't travel until the visa is issued.

Depending on the airline and the conditions under which the ticket was issued, he might be able to get the ticket changed to another day or get a part-refund.

Comment: Yes, so he cancelled the booking for his flight as his visa had not come. But now is the visa going to be rejected? As the travel dates have already passed?