# Can Schengen visa month be changed?

Tags: schengen, denmark

I applied for a Denmark visa 1 month ago. I still did not get it. Now my internship is going to start. If I get the visa during my internship is it possible to change the dates of my visa? Because visa has specified month. Can I change that month? so I avail it after the internship because once my internship starts I can't take leave till 6 weeks. I applied for short term visa as visiting family and friends

Comment: The question is very unclear but chances are your visa will have flexible dates (date of issue + length of your internship and some buffer) or be denied entirely (because it already took a long time and if the date has passed your premise is in doubt). Whatever happens, you cannot easily change anything, you have to reapply or, in exceptional cases, ask the consulate to change the visa for you.

Comment: "I applied for short term visa as visiting family and friends": this is confusing. Why did you do that if you are planning an internship?

Comment: @phoog I read it that OP wanted to make the trip prior to starting internship in home country.

Comment: @Dorothy oh I see, yes, I thought the internship was to be in Denmark, but you are right: it makes much more sense if the internship is in the home country.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visa application in process but travel dates have already gone](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71624/visa-application-in-process-but-travel-dates-have-already-gone)

Answer (score 2):

You applied for a Schengen visa with fixed start/end dates and a duration of one month. The decision is taking longer than normal and you will soon be engaged in a personal commitment (i.e., your internship) and unable to travel for six weeks. What this amalgamates to is that you will not be able to use your Schengen.

> If I get the visa during my internship is it possible to change the
>   dates of my visa?

Schengen visas are inexorably linked to three things...

- a premise for the visit; and
- a start date/end date; and
- an itinerary that is supported with bookings

Completely changing the dates impacts the itinerary because the bookings are no longer valid. And worse, the premise for the visit may have also passed.

> Can I change that month?

Yes but you will need to take two steps...

1. If your visa is issued, you will need to contact them and ask them
   to revoke it because you are unable to travel. A voluntary
   revocation is not a prejudicial thing. Naturally if your application was refused this step isn't needed.
2. Make a fresh application with new bookings and other supporting
   documents.  If your previous application was successful you do not have to submit biometrics again.

Related article: [What are the options when a Schengen visa application is in process after the proposed travel date?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71624/i-applied-for-a-schengen-visa-starting-from-june-17th-but-the-visa-is-still-in)