# My UK visa is still in processing even though the intended date of travel has already passed. Will I still receive a visa?

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for a Standard Visitor visa to the UK stating my travel date as Jan 1st 2017. My appointment was on Dec 15th 2016 but I could make it as I couldn't find a flight. I went to the consulate in Barbados on Jan 5th 2017 for my biometrics and was attended to.

Will I get the visa even though my intended date of travel has passed?

Comment: Related Q for Schengen visas: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71624/i-applied-for-a-schengen-visa-starting-from-june-17th-but-the-visa-is-still-in

Comment: @GayotFow care to add your own answer? I think we need a good canonical on this

Comment: @pnuts Honestly, we do not need an attestation from the OP to know if an answer is correct or not.  The procedures are well defined and there is lots of empirical evidence out there to interpolate for one-off cases. You can comfortably undelete your answer below.  Honestly, take a break.

Comment: No definitive answer. You may or may not. If you applied for a particular event like a meeting/tournament and the time for the event has passed, the probability is less. If for a more open ended event like a vacation, the probabilities are higher. Best.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you have obtained your visa by now but have not yet found the time to report back.

Missing your appointment should have triggered the return of your paperwork and a visa application rejection (ie no decision taken). You were probably lucky to have your biometrics taken when they were. Christmas and New Year holidays may have worked in your favour, other than for the flight issue. Also, appointments are only available once a fortnight anyway so I take it you made it to the first one possible after the one you missed.

Your attending four days after the travel date you indicated is a sign you still wanted the visa and I *suspect* has been interpreted that way. Standard Visitor visas are generally valid for use any time within six months of issue, so it is understood there is time for a change in plans.