# My Schengen Visa refused

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

I had a meeting at my Company's HQ office in Belgium from July 1 to July 15 my embassy's interview was at June 28
I had an accommodating and flight ticket from 1-7 July and of course it has been cancelled finally i've got a refusal from the embassy with code 2 (the purpose and conditions of stay plans have not been justified)
Do you think i've got refused because of intervention between interview date and visit date ?
And what am i suppose to do now especially we have another office meeting at Sep-15 do i have to appeal with the new ticket and accommodation date  15-30 SEP or i have to reapply one more time
*i don't got any stamp on my passport

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You applied for a Schengen on very short notice and by the time they reached a decision, the premise for your visit was no longer valid.  If your application was still in the pipeline when the meeting took place (1 July - 7 July), then it didn't make sense for them to issue the visa.

When these situations arise, the application enters a state they call "incoherence".  When an application is 'incoherent' they use checkbox 2:  "*Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided*".

> Do you think i've got refused because of intervention between
>   interview date and visit date ?

Yes, that's what the indications are based upon the information you have provided.

> And what am i suppose to do now especially we have another office
>   meeting at Sep-15

A different meeting on different dates is a different premise.  You will need to make a fresh application.

> do i have to appeal with the new ticket and accommodation date 15-30 SEP
>   or i have to reapply one more time

**There is no case for them to answer.**  Dates are as mechanical as you can get.

They were correct to refuse and an appeal will get you nowhere. Your most expedient remedy is to make a fresh application from square 1. They have the *option*, but not the *obligation*, to get fresh biometrics from you next time so you might not need to take that step.

> i don't got any stamp on my passport

And?  You will need to declare your previous refusal.

Note: as pointed out by colleague Michael Hamilton (to whom thanks), your question bears a lot of similarity to an existing article here. [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)  You are emphatically advised to read it carefully.

Comment: I Really appreciate your fast reply 
I have one last question when i can submit a new application may i do it immediately or i have to wait 6 months .

Thank you again for your kind reply

Comment: Please its very important for me to know if i can submit a new application immediately 
Thanks

Comment: @user47397: Why would you have to wait 6 months?

Comment: I read this in other forums that if i got refusal so i have to wait 6months before applying a new application 
I trust your answers so do you think i can apply a fresh one immediately?

Comment: Any update please