# Visa refusal in the past

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, singapore

My Husband and I want to apply for a tourist visa to Singapore in November 2016. However, we have a past visa rejection from France and Italy (last year in December). Will this affect our future visa application with Singapore?

Comment: Possibly. There is no data sharing (that I know of) and certainly no legal consequences (formally, even France or Italy have to evaluate a new application on its own merit rather than decline based on the previous refusal) but a consular officer might see the stamps and be extra careful. More broadly, and even if the legal framework is probably quite different, the conditions that led to the refusal in France might also have the same effect in Singapore.

Comment: Hi Zach thanks for the prompt response. The reason for our France and Italy visa refusal was " reason for the visit is not justified". We never understood what that meant. We were just travelling for our honeymoon and had mentioned the same in the application too. Plus we had applied via a travel agent. And now we are unsure if we will ever travel again. do you know if there is a statue of limitations on past visa refusals?

Comment: No there is not, because there is no ban in the first place. Like I said, you are free to re-apply immediately, even to France. You might get another refusal of course but it's not automatic so it wouldn't make sense to have a “statute of limitation” of some sort. IIRC, the database records will be deleted in five years. For some clues on how to interpret the refusal, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Answer (score 4):

You would probably not be refused, as I don't think Schengen states and Singapore share this information in the first place, and even if they do, if you provide the proper paperwork you should be fine.

Many countries do ask in their visa application forms whether you've ever been refused a visa in any country. If you're honest about it (which I recommend you to be), processing delays are not unlikely.

Whilst it is not likely that Singapore would catch you lying about a refusal for France (unless it's visible in the passport) if they do have some means of catching you, you're in much hotter water than if you had been honest.

Personally, I would apply, answer all questions truthfully, and be patient.