# What can I do about my Schengen visa refusal?

Tags: schengen, france, visa-refusals

My Schengen visa got refused and one of the reasons are "Your intention to leave the member states before your visa expiration is not justified".

What should I do to solve it and where did I go wrong? the another question is also my another reason and I have solved that but I am confused about this problem

Comment: One of the reasons ? What are the others ? What documents did you submit with your application ? What's the full text of the refusal letter ?

Comment: Also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Comment: other reasons are " You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence for the duration of the intended stay or for the return to the country of origin or residence, or for the transit to a third country into which you are certain to be admitted, or you are not in a position to acquire such means lawfully."and " The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable." I have submitted paper according to their website