# Family's visa to accompany me on a business trip was denied

Tags: schengen, france, visa-refusals, family

I applied for a Schengen business visa through the French Embassy and also applied for visitor visas for my family so that they could travel with me.

I got the visa but my one-year-old child's and my wife's visa applications were rejected. The stated reason was that 'the purpose and conditions of the proposed visit have not been justified.'

I wanted to combine a business visit with tourism with my family after finishing my work. I don't understand the reason for rejection.

Should I appeal the decision or apply for new visa?

We were planning to stay in Belfort and the hotel booking was for 15 days for the three of us.

Comment: How long is the trip for and what country are you a pertinent resident in / what country is your passport?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)