# Is there a minimum of work experience i should have for schengen visa?

Tags: visas

I am referring to the tax return that is required for schengen visa? What's the minimum of years of work exerience i should have to be qualified for it?

Comment: To the official who is evaluating your application, your employment is a kind of evidence to show that you will return home after your trip and not stay. A very good job that you have recently gotten -- good pay and benefits -- can seem like a better reason to return than working a poor job for many years (hard work, low pay,long hours.)

Answer (score 3):

The [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=URISERV%3Ajl0028) lays out all of the conditions a person must meet in order to qualify. The requirements are expressed in broad terms and subject to detailed (and sometimes captious) interpretations by the visa officials.

Having said that, there are no explicit requirements for an applicant to have worked a certain number of years. In fact there are no explicit boundaries anywhere in the code.   People who qualify are those who demonstrate a stable and well-anchored lifestyle, and one good way to show that is a stable record of continuous employment, BUT it is not the only way.

> I am referring to the tax return that is required for schengen visa?

A tax return is not required as evidence.  There are times and situations where I have advised people to include their tax returns, but these were generally self-employed individuals who were running their affairs out of their pockets and had poor banking exhibits.  Moreover, a tax return is not high quality evidence when submitted by itself, and for those people it was a stop-gap against submitting nothing at all.

> What's the minimum of years of work exerience i should have to be
>   qualified for it?

As explained above, the Visa Code is free from any sort of qualifying hurdles. Accordingly, there is no minimum.  The real question is: *how can my employment history be used to demonstrate a stable lifestyle?* And the answer is that your payslips and bank statements will speak for themselves. In short, nothing else is needed.

For you personally, I have seen from your previous questions that you have been working for about 7 months.  This can be seen as your saving enough for a one-way trip into the 'zone' and will go underground once you are there.  Combined with your age (mid-20's), you have a **very borderline case**.  It means you will face difficulty in establishing a credible premise along with showing your willingness to abide the terms and conditions of a visa.  Based on everything you have provided, they will most likely select [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

But this article ([Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)) would also be a possible, but less likely, outcome.

Comment: Thanks.In case my visa gets rejected or approved is there any tool online where i can check it, even after I would already know that

Comment: Wait. You asked your question and you got your answer. That's how the site works. It is not well-received to introduce new material in comments or to ignore the value of the information you received. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers with a view towards understanding the site, thanks.