# Visa refusal appeal

Tags: spain, pakistani-citizens

I had applied for a spanish tourist visa with my family. I am the citizen  of  Pakistan. I had submitted  all the required  documents but my visa was refused [image: The objections they put for my visa refusal and the letter I received] I want to ask

- Is there chance of getting  my appeal approved if I add some supporting  documents?
- Can I email my appeal letter  and supporting  documents?? If yes than how?

Comment: Appeals have low probability of success.

Comment: If you can fix your application by adding more supporting documents, it is best to simply reapply. You cannot appeal based on you havIng left information out on first application.

Comment: i dont get it, was you visa apply refused and you want to appeal??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ 웃 Пepeúpaツ   yes my visa apply was refused!! And I want to appeal!!

Answer (score 3):

In general you need *very*, *very* strong arguments that the decision was wrong (given the information they had at the time) to be successful with an appeal. Remember: a visa is not something you're entitled to, it's something you can be granted if you can provide strong enough arguments that you should get one, and the staff at the embassy are basically free to decide either way they want to.

If you have to add additional documents, it's really not an appeal but a new application!

Just make sure you understand the reasons given, see e.g.

- [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)
- [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

and address those issue in a new application.