# Netherlands Schengen Visa Refusal

Tags: schengen-visas, netherlands, vfs-global

I have made a visa application for traveling in Netherlands through VFS Global in Russia (Yekaterinburg). The application was triple checked and was accompanied by all the required documents including:

- Print of plane tickets from Moscow to Amsterdam (24-02-2019) and backwards (03-03-2019) with verifiable booking code
- Print of valid half-prepayed booking in Amsterdam hotel for staying from 24-02-2019 to 03-03-2019 from booking.com
- A verifiable bank inquiry showing 1000 EUR on my bank account that I have not even touched since the inquiry was emitted

The application was rejected with next message:

> Sufficient justification for the purpose and circumstances of the intended stay was not provided. You were unable to provide sufficient plausible, verifiable information about the purpose and circumstances of your stay. Consequently, it cannot be determined with sufficient certainty that all the conditions for ifs its have been met.
>
> Sufficient justification for the purpose and circumstances of the intended stay was not provided. Your travel ticket reservation is no longer valid, and no other reservation has been made in its place. Consequently, the purpose of your journey cannot be confimied.
>
> Justification for the purpose and circumstances of the intended stay was not provided. Your hotel reservation has lapsed, and no other reservation has been made in its place. As a result, the purpose of your journey cannot be confirmed.
>
> Sufficient justification for the purpose and circumstances of the intended stay was not provided. Although you have stated that the primary place of residence during your trip is in the member state of destination you indicated, this is not supported by the documents submitted.

Moreover, the receipt of submission fee (image below) payed by VFS Global (to The Embassy or something with website buzaservices.nl that unaccessible from Russia, idk) that I received with the rejection have traveling period from 22-02-2019 to 08-04-2019.

I have no idea what can possibly go wrong as:

- VFS Global is 100% not scam and recommended by The Netherlands Embassy
- Booking.com and the hotel officially confirms my booking for this dates
- The airlines also confirms my already bought tickets

As I was marked as rejected applicant with severe refusal reason, The Embassy of Netherlands in Russia don't want to do anything to resolve this situation and don't say anything besides the reasons described in rejection.

The questions is:

- How can I lodge the decision? (What should I appeal to?)
- What should I get (except saved reputation) if the appeal will success after the end of traveling period requested in application?
- Should the traveling period from the receipt below be equal to traveling period from the application and can it be VFS mistake?

Thanks.

[image: the receipt of submission fee]

P.S. I am posting this question on behalf of my fiancee, whom I should travel with

UPD 14.02.2019:
After a series of calls to VFS Global they told me that the first date of traveling period from the receipt is gets as two days before the requested period. The second date is generated AUTOMATICALLY by the system the application data was put in.
Also we have sent the objection letter to IDL using address from the rejection letter.

Comment: You just may be a victim of international relation between Russia and EU. In any case it seems you provided no reasons for the travel. Will you travel alone? What do you plant to visit? [Russian sex worker in Nederland are reality, you should proof that you are not such person (or you need to apply an other visa)]

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I should travel with my fiancé, his plane ticket was also included in the application (as it was printed on one piece of paper). The booking also contained his name as the second guest.
In the application, the purpose of the trip was indicated as tourism. Are plane tickets and hotel booking insufficient to prove it?

Comment: The "travelling period" says until 08-04-2019. That's a 6 week stay, not 1 week. Do you have an idea what happened there? In combination with a 1000 EUR budget, I can see how that leads to a rejection.

Comment: @MSalters I don't have any idea, why traveling period differs from indicated in the application (1 week vs 6 week). I don't personally payed for the service this receipt associated with (I guess it was payed by VFS Global).

Answer (score 8):

In NL, the process of disputing your visa refusal is called ["objecting" to the decision](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/objecting-to-the-decision-to-refuse-your-visa-application). If you feel your application was not processed correctly, you can provide an objection in writing.

The visa refusal letter that you receive has instructions on how to submit your objection and includes the mailing address where you should mail it to.

Your objection letter should explain why you believe the visa application was not processed correctly. Avoid language that might be perceived as rude, and simply present facts. For example: "The refusal letter said that my travel ticket reservation was no longer valid, but $AIRLINE still shows me a valid booking number #####." Repeat this for every fact in dispute.

If your objection is successful, you will be advised to make an appointment with the consulate or with VFS Global to bring in your passport to receive the visa.

Comment: @Mark Kotevode It may help you to read this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Comment: @Traveller Not that one; there's a [different question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52782/3221) that generally explains his refusal reason. But this isn't a duplicate because he is specifically saying that his visa application wasn't processed correctly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's not being proposed as a duplicate; just something that would be helpful to read.