# Denied Schengen Visa twice, what should I do?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens

I hold a Nigerian Passport and I was invited to Netherlands for a final set of interviews. I have completed 4 stages of interview already but I was refused with the first time with this reason "Justifications for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided".

After the first denial, the company called the embassy to ask why and they were advised to provide a cover letter to the embassy detailing the purpose of my visit. This was provided together with the company's registration document for my second application. So I submitted the following to justify my case:

-Invitation from the company to me

-Cover letter to the embassy

-The company's registration document

After a week, I also got an email from the visa office asking for an introduction from my current company which I sent back the same day. But I was surprised to be denied a second time for the same reason "Justifications for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided".

Please advise, what can I do next? Will an appeal affect my chances if I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten) Is the company paying your trip expenses? You are flagging to the ECO that you plan to work in The Netherlands, what evidence of ties to Nigeria did you provide to demonstrate a reason to return home after the interview?

Comment: I provided my current employment letter, bank account statement, and marriage certificate

Comment: First, see the guidance in the duplicate question linked above. After that, you can file a new application with new information, or if you believe the Netherlands embassy did not process your visa application correctly, you may dispute the refusal by [filing an objection](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/132113/3221).