# Schengen Visa got rejected by Netherlands embassy. Where and how should I reapply? [India]

Tags: visa-refusals, france, schengen-visas, netherlands, visa-rejections

I am travelling to Europe on August 5th. Itinerary is: Arrival in Barcelona, 3 days there, 3 days in Paris, 4 in Amsterdam and 4 in Belgium and then back. I am from India and have never travelled outside of India. I applied for schengen at Netherlands and got a reject. The reason is:

> *"The Purpose and circumstance of the intended stay are insufficiently demonstrated.  Sufficient justification for the purpose and
>   circumstances of the intended stay was not provided."*

I provided the following documents:

1. Accommodation for all four countries,
2. To and from flight confirmed tickets
3. Leave letter from employer
4. Bank account statements and sufficient account balance
5. Insurance
6. Internal travel tickets(train)
7. Cover letter stating that I am visiting for tourism

I am unable to understand what is missing in the documents and why the visa was rejected.

Which of the below options is my best bet to get the visa:

1. Apply again to Netherlands with a more detailed cover letter(do not
   know what else I can change), but Netherlands takes more time to
   process and I am short of time.
2. Change my itinerary and spend 6-7 days in France instead and apply to the French embassy (which is faster, usually)

Please let me know if there are any suggestions/inputs.

Comment: Your lack of travel history may have played a part in the decision. Possible duplicate of [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)