# got refusal two times from Swiss Embassy,

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, international-travel, schengen-visas, tips-and-tricks

Hi i had tried two times from Swiss embassy with my cousin sister . When I was tried first time I did not have much more travel history only had Thailand Visa. I had show my salary only 20000/- per month and and her 15000/- my fund was just made in one month around 2 lac. my ITR was around 2.5 lac without.

So i thought that was a biggest mistake from my side because our funds and salaries was too low. than i again try last year in 14 august 2018. That times We have got Thailand, Singapore, Indonesia,and Dubai Visa on our Passport. I had show my salary 25000/- and her 19000/- and Funds was around 5 lac per person but its deposited in a month only and all are cash deposits. My stay was around 4 nights in Switzerland and 3 nights in Austria. Flights are just hold not booked and Hotel was just booked but without payment my visa company created a Tour itinerary according to the Visa process Condition But again I got refusal.

Now we are again going to try now i have maintained my funds from last 6 months and showing my salary 40000/- and her 32000/- per month in bank account with online transfer. ITR my 4.40 lac and her 3.90 lac. funds are maintained 3 lac per persons.and now we having 3 more visa Hong Kong, Macau and China.

So my Question is should i try or not? Please Suggest me what should i do?

Edit: the refusal reason was “Your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa applied for could not be ascertained.“

Comment: What was the refusal reason? That is the most important bit.

Comment: Is your salary still being deposited in cash? That’s often a huge negative. Was the refusal reason(s) the same both times? You’ll get better answers if you post a copy of the refusal letter with your personal details blanked out, or you can edit your question to include the reason(s).

Comment: yes it was deposited by cash  may be that is the reason of refusal... but now from 1 January 2019 i have depositing bye Cheque and in statements it showing properly.. 40000 per month.

Comment: If you don’t tell us the refusal reason(s) we can’t try to answer your question. Reading https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten might help you

Comment: Your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa applied for could not be ascertained.

Comment: The above reason i got last year

Comment: Note that even 40000 INR is only a about 580 swiss francs, which is less than the minimum wage in most Schengen countries, a lot less than the minimum wage in many of them, and below the poverty line in Switzerland. They would definitely not see this as enough incentive for you to return to India rather than trying to stay in the Schengen Area. You probably need to show more ties to your home country (partner, kids, parents you need to take care of, property....).

Comment: What is the reason you want visit Switzerland, and how much are you intending to spend on the trip? Do you know people there?

Comment: Note that Switzerland stipulates that foreign nationals bearing their own costs of their stay in Switzerland must prove that they possess approx. CHF 100 per day. Austria does not specify a reference amount for subsistence, it is on a case-by-case basis. https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25.pdf Did you apply for a single entry or a multi entry visa when you were refused?

Comment: You said you have five visas in your passport. Did you actually travel to those five places? How did you get the money to do that?

Comment: yes i have visited these countries......... 30 Aug 2016 to 2 Sep 2016 in Hotel IBIS Bangkok,...2 Sep 2016 to 7 Sep 2016 in Dusit Thane Resort Phuket  Thailand.....

Comment: 2 Sep 2017 to 7 Sep 2017 in Hotel Boss ..Singapore... 7 Sep 2017 to 9 Sep 2017 in Bintan Lagoon Resort , Bintan Indonesia

Comment: 7 Feb 2018 to 13 Feb 2018 in Majestic Hotel Tower  in Dubai

Comment: 13 Sep 2018 to 17 Sep 2018 in Harbour Plaza Metropolis ...HongKong.... 17 Sep 2018 to 19 Sep In Grand palace Hotel in China....19 Sep 2018 to 23 Sep 2018 Hotel Venetian Macau...

Comment: I only Spend my whole salary for travels and this is my dream to cover all the world.... but from the starting i wish to travel Europe because Switzerland in my childhood dream but this is  my bad luck i got denied two times from Swiss Embassy

Comment: i know that 40000 is too low for visit Switzerland but If you calculate for the whole year it comes 480000 and right now my funds are almost 3 lac.. Is it enough or not ? Please suggest me otherwise i will go somewhere else...

Comment: I am working from last 12 years As a General Manager in  a Hotel. and i am travelling from last 5 years but those are my international trips before that i had only visited in india..

Comment: I want to visit Switzerland only for tourist purpose. And I can spend approx 2.5 lac on this trip..  and i do not have any relatives or friends in Switzerland

Comment: Please help me out ..... Please suggest me what should i do?