# Long term accommodation proof for Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, proof-of-accommodation

A friend of mine needs to apply for a Schengen visa to France, it is for three months of medical training. The hospital, where he will be doing my training, does not provide accommodation.

Since his visa approval is not guaranteed at all, he doesn't want to book an apartment without the visa, specially I think it is impossible to get a three month refundable booking.

So he decided to book a hotel for five days (refundable) and then if he gets the visa he will stay in the hotel while searching for an apartment.

The visa officer rejected his application based on no proof of accommodation. What do you think he should do or should have done

Comment: And in regards to the question, did you explain this in the application, that you had the 5 day hotel and planned to get further accommodation after visa had been granted, or did you just attach proof of the hotel?

Comment: @Uciebila as for the explanation, he did not explain on forms, I advised him to explain at interview but he did not have the chance..

Comment: Why does your friend say he was refused for no proof of accommodation? He has omitted important details. What exactly happened?

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for letting me look at the refusal letter again. I wrongly understood the French

"l’objet et les conditions du séjour envisagé n’ont pas été justifiés"

in English it traslates to "the purpose and conditions of the intended stay were not justified" which actually has nothing to with proof of accommodation. So sorry for the confusion

Comment: In that case, see [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52782/3221)