# Processing a visa application with a past expected travel date

Tags: visa-refusals, europe, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas

As a non-EU national, if I apply for a visa on the 15th and state that the expected date of travel is on, say 20th, but once the visa is started processing, that date has already passed, would that affect the visa result?

Comment: It takes time to process a visa application. Why would you do this?

Answer (score 4):

We've seen numerous examples over the years of people who have applied for Schengen visas with itineraries that were in the past at the time the application was processed. The usual response is that the visa is refused with the reason [Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52782/3221).

If you feel like wasting 60 euros, and possibly having an adverse immigration history, this is probably a good way to do it.

Comment: My intention is not deliberate; for example, I want to apply for a visa and travel as soon as possible, but I fear that if the date is too early, they might refure is because by the time they start processing the visa, the date might have already passed.

Comment: Do you not have specific travel plans, then?!

Comment: Yes, in fact I have