# What could be the reason for Visa refusal below?

Tags: visas, schengen, work, estonia

I hold a Namibian passport and work as a customer service representative. I recently applied for an Estonian national work visa to work as a food server. I attached supporting documents such as an Estonia work permit, a bank statement, travel insurance, a letter from Estonia employer

In addition to the mandatory documents on my visa application, I attached a cover letter in which I stated that my intention is to work in Estonia in order to obtain sufficient funds to finance my established businesses in Namibia, and I attached registration certificates as proof, but unfortunately, I received a refusal letter with reasons below.

> (1-there are reasonable doubts regarding your intention to leave the territory of the Republic of Estonia before the expiry of the visa;
>
> (2-you have not justified the purpose and conditions of the intended stay;
>
> there are reasonable doubts regarding the reliability of the statements you made about the purpose of your stay in the territory of the Republic of Estonia due to the evidence that is available to the authority or due to objective circumstances indicating that the purpose of the stay could be different than declared;

Comment: Basically they didn't believe you, that's what it says. Why? We can't know since we don't know what documents you provided vs what they wanted/expected to see, and even if you tell us what you provided, we still won't know what they wanted or expected to see.

Comment: This looks like a credibility issue. For example, if you have ‘established businesses’ in Namibia, why do you need to go to work as a food server (probably not a well-paid job, maybe not particularly secure employment)? Why Estonia? Related questions https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Comment: What is an “Estonia work permit”? How did you apply? How did you find an employer? Did you use the services of an agency? Have you had previous visa refusals (from any country)? What duration of stay did you apply for?

Comment: @Traveller the business in Namibia was impacted by covid, which is why I decided to go and work in estonia to get some funding

Comment: @jcaron i using an agency because its difficult to get direct hire,

Comment: Also, what is the salary your employer committed to?

Comment: Did you actually have any contact with the employer? Some agencies are reliable, but a lot are just crooks praying on vulnerable people. Some go as far as providing false documents, and you then end up with a negative history.

Comment: @jcaron salary is €6 per hour

Comment: @jcaron yes we have been in touch and i have already sent msg.

Comment: I personally highly doubt there is any job or employer. To register a non-EU foreign worker you need to commit to pay them way above the average salary for restaurant waiters, which makes it quite unlikely.

Comment: @jcaron that means there's also issue regarding the stated salary on the job offer.

Comment: From what I understand, 6 euros per hour is way below the minimum required to grant registration or a work visa. See https://www2.politsei.ee/en/teenused/working-in-estonia/registration-of-short-term-employment/oluline-info-luhiajalise-tootamise-registreerijale.dot#palk

Comment: @littleadv i have stated the documents i provided, do u have any suggestions how i can correct that? I attached business details to demonstrate proof of ties in my home country

Comment: @Euna If you can leave your business in Namibia to go to work in Estonia, your business details are probably useless as proof of ties to your home country, unless eg it has been operating for some time, is profitable, and you can prove that it will continue operating while you’re out of Namibia. You would need to show other ties. Do you have a dependent partner/children in Namibia? Do you own property there?

Comment: @yes i have some properties and childrens but im not legally married, in my appeal i should include children and my partner. Other section 2 and 3 justfing the purpose and conditions of intended stay any suggestions

Comment: You probably don't have any practical recourse to be honest. An appeal may be a waste of money. Given the earlier discussion and without knowing much about Estonia specifically (but quite a bit about other European countries), I would be concerned that the agency you used is just trying to get more money from you.

Comment: Incidentally, the reasons quoted are standard refusal reasons for short-stay visas. It's possible Estonia is also using them for other types of visas (there is no rule against that) but it's also possible that the agency applied for the wrong type of visa. An appeal won't solve that either.

Comment: @Relaxed I contacted the agency, and they promised to take care of it, but I'm not sure. I'm afraid that if I appeal again, I'll end up losing even more money. I've already lost $4000.

Comment: If you paid them $4000 to apply for a visa it’s nearly certainly a scam. Did you actually apply for the visa yourself or did they handle that on your behalf? It’s even possible they didn’t even apply for the visa (which would be, all things considered, good news for you). Which embassy did you deal with?

Comment: Mmmm I just noted you wrote “if I appeal again”. Did you already apply, get rejected, and appeal?

Comment: Note that there is strictly no chance an appeal will be successful. Beyond your personal circumstances which you could maybe address, the fact is you simply do not qualify for a D visa for Estonia based on the salary, and there is no way you could get paid above the required threshold for that job. If your application was actually submitted you are also now in the VIS so have very little chance of getting a visa elsewhere in Schengen, and probably further as in many applications you’ll have to disclose the fact you got a visa refusal.

Comment: @jcaron All of the documents they provided are legitimate because the embassy verified them prior to my appearance, but I'm not sure what went wrong. For appeal again its typing error. I haven't made appeal, thats why im seeking advice from here

Comment: If you could please take the time to review all comments and answers all the questions raised (you didn't provide any info for at least half of the points raised) it would allow to draw a more accurate picture of your situation. At this time we don't know the duration of work, the monthly salary, the length of the visa, which embassy you dealt with, what is the "work permit" you say you submitted (please edit your post to include a copy with your personal details blacked out). The salary may not be an issue if it qualifies for "seasonal work" but that is limited in time, for instance.