# Belgium visa refusal

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, belgium

I went to Europe several times without any problems. I got Schengen visas from Dubai and Doha many times without any refusal. Recently, I applied for a new Schengen visa from Belgium, but I got a refusal for: "justification for purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided". What can I do now? It is not logical to me.

Comment: Has anything material (job, family ties, purpose/length of intended stay etc) changed since your previous applications? Does this answer your question? [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

Comment: Without any details it’s quite difficult for anyone to give much advice. What was the reason for the trip? Tourism, business…? Did you provide an itinerary and all required documents? Are the costs consistent with your revenues? What’s your citizenship and place of residence? What is your situation (permanent, well paid job…)? What are your ties to your country of residence? Did you provide evidence of those ties?

Comment: Also, which countries did you get visas from previously? Different countries, with different economies, may have very different thresholds…