Schengen Visa from Spain refused
I was just refused my Schengen visa on grounds that justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay not provided, and means of subsistence not provided, I'd like to mention that I want to appeal but they have given my passport one week short of travel date.
So should I justify my old itinerary or make a new itinerary and ask them? In case of new, I need to change my NOC etc as well which will take a month or so. Should I go with old NOC and old dates? Or completely new itinerary for the appeal?

First: are you sure you understand the real problem? Gives you application to a friend and ask him/her to evaluate it. Probably you assumed too much, and visa officers didn't have such information. So probably you forgot to include relevant information. Without a clear understanding of the refusal, you just risk to lose time and money. -- in other words: I do not think the itinerary was a problem, but on lack of other documents

It might be wise to read (and understand): https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

On what basis do you think you have grounds to appeal? How sure are you that you submitted a strong application (full documentary evidence, a good travel history, compelling reason to leave etc)? It might help to read this

Assuming you applied in Pakistan, bear on mind that the rejection rate for short stay visas for Spain was around 60% in 2023, I doubt it’s improved since then.

You also mention the reason "means of subsistence not provided", i.e. they do not think you have enough money to pay for this trip. How do you plan to appeal this part of the rejection? IMO, this is the more important one.


So should I justify my old itinerary or make a new itinerary and ask them? In case of new, I need to change my NOC, etc. as well which will take a month or so. Should I go with old NOC and old dates? Or completely new itinerary for the appeal?

In general, an appeal makes sense if you want to dispute the legal reasoning behind the original decision but not to fix a weak application. An appeal will also take time and isn't very likely to succeed. I don't know about Spain specifically but weeks or months, up to a couple of years to get an answer and overturn rates in the single digits are not unheard of in other countries.
So your appeal is very unlikely to be resolved satisfactorily within one week and the refusal effectively forces you to postpone the trip. This means that you now need a new itinerary, new NOC, etc. Again, I don't know about Spanish procedure specifically but chances are that a court or other authority hearing your appeal might simply refuse to consider this new evidence and only focus on the original application.
An appeal therefore seems to be the wrong procedure in your situation. Instead, you should consider a fresh application (but do not rush to do that either, it's best to take the time to understand what might have gone wrong and prepare a really strong application).

I believe the problem here is much deeper and you need to carefully consider the reasons for the rejection before thinking about an appeal. Usually, an appeal is to challenge the legal reasons for rejection, not to fix an application, and not just to give it another try.
Much of the details needed to comment on this particular case are missing but from what you have written:

justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay not provided,
and means of subsistence not provided,

It appears the visa officer has serious doubts about your real intentions and plan to visit Spain, and your financial resources for the trip. Most developed countries assume by default that you're an illegal immigrant and the onus to prove otherwise (i.e., you are there for a legitimate reason, you have the financial resources to easily cover the trip, and you have strong reasons to return to your country before the expiry of your visa) are on the applicant. Some countries like the US state this explicitly but almost all countries consider this.
You mention that you need a new NOC so I take it you're either a govt. employee or that of a bank or semi-govt. organization. If you were going on official business or an event, giving a new itinerary makes no sense and does not justify the reason since it will have already passed. So your appeal won't be justified. If this was for tourism, then your best bet is to re-apply after some time but only if you can strongly justify your application, e.g., a strong travel history, strong and legitimate financial and professional ties to Pakistan, and a solid and justifiable travel plan.
While you can consult a travel agent or lawyer for advice after seeing the particulars of your application and rejection letter, an appeal doesn't look justifiable from what you have shared.
